# Datatrigger with DynamicResource works only on last item in ItemsControl

Tags: xaml, datatemplate, itemscontrol, datatrigger, dynamicresource

My `DashBoardSimpleCountObject` has 2 values: `MyName` and `MyValue`.
I use an `ObservableCollection<DashboardSimpleCountObject>` called `MyData`.

I want to show a picture, as long as `MyValue` is `null`.
However, the picture ("`loading`") is only shown at the last item of my `ObservableCollection` (no matter, how many items are in there). As soon as a `MyValue` is set (with anything other than `null`), it is automatically updated and shown correctly - that works fine at all items.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="_control" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="25">
                <Label FontSize="14" Content="{Binding MyName}" />
                <Label Margin="0,25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontSize="29" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="{Binding MyColor}">
                    <Label.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding MyValue}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyValue}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="{DynamicResource loading}" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Label.Style>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Just found out, it has something to do with the `DynamicResource`. If I don't set the `Content` to an image in the `DataTrigger`, but to some default text, it works like it should. It seems, the picture will load in one single item only.

Comment: I took quite some time to google and find a solution, but obviously didn't know, what to look for - as I didn't suspect the problem to lie with `DynamicResource`. So, sorry for the "bad" question - I try to do better next time. (Still, posting a question on here is always my **last** straw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the nature of `DynamicResource` causes this issue.
Simply changing `DynamicResource` to `StaticResource` did the trick.

So, the `DataTrigger` worked just fine from the beginning. The image simply did only show up once due to being loaded as a `DynamicResource`.